# Function with getter value

Tags: javascript, function, getter

I would like to create function with a getter function. The function should be callable with `(arguments)` or without parentheses.
ex.:

```
function play (song) {
    if (song){
        //  play song...
    } else {
        //  play resume song...
    }
}
```

and then calling `play()` and `play` would yield same result, but you could still do `play(song)`.

Is there any way to do this?

PS:

```
play()    //  Called sucesfully
play      //  Returned reference to function - wrong
play(song)    //  Called sucesfully
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you just wrote?

Comment: Calling play will return reference to the function not call the function itself. (edited)

Comment: Why do you want a variable act like a function?

Comment: When you're calling `play` without brackets. You just **referencing** the function, not executing it (or invoking) a function. The other way somehow you may did is create the variable that reference to you `play` function.

Comment: Still what you need is not clear, do you want to use brackets when you want to Play the song, and no brackets when you need to Know the current playing status?

Comment: It's possible what you want to do (using `with` and getters and higher-order functions), but **you really should not**.

Comment: What is the real problem you're solving with this?

Comment: @Shadi I want both to do same thing

Comment: You're so lazy that you're saving 2 keystrokes for `()`?

Comment: @Bergi Interesting, could you show me how? Just to learn something new PS: write in head that is should not be done ;)

Comment: @zerkms Exactly and I am learning new things this way too...

Comment: So this is the new thing to learn: functions are invoked with `()`, and one does not invoke functions implicitly without `()`

Comment: @Akxe: Or actually, it's not even possible like that, as `play()` would be *two* function calls then, and your function logic won't like that.

Comment: @Bergi So it ain't possible at all? Sad...

Comment: Not "sad" but fortunate: even without such weirdness the code around us is terrible.

Comment: @Akxe: Well it's possible to call a function with `play` and to call that and a second function with `play()`, but that's not really useful, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can call a function without using parentheses, using the additions in ECMAScript 5th edition

Here's an example of calling a function without using parentheses using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and defining it as a getter:

```
var o = {};
var bValue = 38;
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
  get: function() { return bValue; },
  set: function(newValue) { bValue = newValue; }
});
o.b; // 38
```

#### EDIT

try this

```
Function.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this();
}
Function.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.valueOf().toString();
}

function play(song) { 
    if (song) {
        console.log('if case');
    } else {
        console.log('else case');
    }
}

play; // else case
play(true); // if case
```

caution: this overrides `valueOf` and `toString` methods of `Function`.

Comment: I am aware of this, but this is usable only for values, not for functions, right?

Comment: I was looking for more details and found [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/is-it-possible-to-call-a-function-without-parenthesis/3890/9). I updated my answer based on it

Comment: @Venugopal: did you also understand what it does? It won't work for a simple `play;` statement.

Comment: In JavaScript, `valueOf` and `toString` are sister methods inherited by every object. One of these methods will get invoked based on the need. if the expression hints at the need for a string then `toString` is invoked,  otherwise its `valueOf`. as per [moz docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)
"JavaScript calls the `valueOf` method to convert an object to a primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the `valueOf` method yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected."

Comment: generally if you use a function without parantheses, its `valueOf` function gets invoked and returns the function definition. here, we are overriding the `valueOf` function where we are actually invoking the function using `this()`.

Comment: Can you also assign to `play`?

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript using () is the proper syntax for a function call, using the function name without it makes sense only in that kind of context.

Assigning function reference:

```
surface.ondraw = myfunction;
```

Getting actual result of the function call:

```
result = myfunction();
```

This is just how javascript syntax works no mystery here I think.

Comment: There is yet setters and gettres funtions